# Turning into a puddle of blood

Tags: biology, magic, creature-design, mythical-creatures, vampires

Vampires have that weird innate skill of being able to turn into a blood puddle and then morph back into a vampire. 
This is an evolved characteristic all vampires share.

The Arcanists and scholars of our kingdom have problems understanding how and why such behavior has evolved.

What is the most likely explanation as to how it evolved and why vampires do it?

Comment: "Vampires have that weird innate skill of being able to turn into a blood puddle" Are you saying that is the case in your world, or that such is the case with vampire mythology? I ask because I have never heard of such a vampire ability before. I'm not a vampire expert, but I've heard of a lot of the folklore and fantasy: garlic, wood, water, turn into bats, etc., etc. but have never heard of anything like this in any myth or fiction.

Comment: No no... nothing to do with standard mythology.

Comment: It is permissible to use Worldbuilding Stack Exchange as a space for exploring ideas unique to your fictional world, and to help find specific answers to developed queries, we prefer questions which are not just preference / opinion, as in many cases the simplest answer becomes "your world, your mechanics, your handwaving - you explain it!" ... and with literal evolutionary biology, traits are *not* evolved for a purpose as though designed (teleology) but rather random mutations of genes resulting in new traits which, when combined with a selective pressure, may give rise to advantage.

Comment: As such this question has close votes against it as being primarily opinion-based - I suggest reading through our help center [https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help] to develop your question such that the information and input you seek is no longer primarily conflicting opinion battles.

Comment: For more details on asking great questions: [ask]

Comment: @GerardFalla What makes it too opinion-based? The OP said the answers would be ranked by plausibility. Does the question need to ask for specific citations? I think it follows most of the rules in the [guidelines for subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). I think 4-6 could be fixed by improving the requirements in the question.

Comment: @JohnLocke - exactly - if OP works on the question a bit, I think it'd fly fine.

Comment: @Gorman Do you want me to edit? If so, I would add a requirement for specific citations of existing organisms with similar traits. I think that would fix the potential for low-quality answers. Having good examples would also help with ranking questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They don't actually turn into a puddle of blood, they just appear to in order to confuse and escape predators.

Much like how [some squids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_ink) expel ink to escape predators, vampires evolved the ability to expel the blood they drink. When they see a predator running at them, they expel a thick mist of blood to blind the predator and act as a smokescreen for their escape. If they are already caught, they are able to secrete liquid blood to slip the predator's grasp and cover the predator in slick blood.

The Arcanists and scholars believe they actually turn into puddles because their knowledge is mainly based on [sensationalized stories and traditional doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleus_Maleficarum) regarding these hard-to-catch vampires. Stories include cornered vampires exploding in a shower of blood only to be found feasting again the next day, and vampires that escaped from their cells by pouring themselves through the barred window, leaving behind no trace but a smear of blood.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to compare to squid ink.  There are real animals that spray blood as a defense mechanism.  There's even a term for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autohaemorrhaging

Answer (score 2):

The stated ability is an excellent form of camouflage, and it evolved b/c it helps a vampire to both hunt prey, and escape from predators.

The bigger issue is this ability is very hard to do for any reasonably complex organism, especially for one with bones. Bones take forever to form naturally, so de-constructing and re-forming them will likely take a long long time, and leave the vampire very vulnerable during that time.

Even with soft tissues, returning to normal form from a puddle means that every cell in the body knows where to go, and has a way of getting there.

Alternatively, Vampires are **colonial organisms**. Every cell can play any function in the body, and it can tell what it is supposed to do. Or maybe a small % of cells specialize in serving as nerve cells, and supervise other cells assembling themselves back into upright shape. 
See this Q for more ideas:
[Sentient colonial organisms?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/128512/sentient-colonial-organisms)